# Use jar to create a jar file over a folder

Tags: java, jar

I see someone is using the following command to create a `jar` file from a folder containing many Java packages (i.e. sub folders)

`jar cvf program.jar -C folder1/folder2/folder3 .`

It seems the command won't work without the last `.`. And I tried to use `*` instead. Also works.

So what does the last `.` or `*` mean?

Comment: The current working directory. You did type 'man jar'?

Comment: I am using Windows. I know a `.` usually means current folder. But I just don't see how it fits here. Because I already feed the `-C` value to look under `folder1/folder2/folder3` recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [jar documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

-C option changes to the specified directory and adds the next file to the jar.

Example:

jar cf ImageAudio.jar -C images . -C audio .

The -C images part of this command directs the Jar tool to go to the images directory, and the . following -C images directs the Jar tool to archive all the contents of that directory. The -C audio . part of the command then does the same with the audio directory.

So, in your example, you will add to the jar the content of folder1/folder2/folder3 directory.

Comment: Thanks. When I use the Windows command `copy folder1\. folder2`, the sub folder of folder1 is not copied to folder2. But with `jar` command, it seems `.` has implied the recursiveness. I am new to Java so this is kind of out of my expectation.